Set of zero-divisors in a ring is a union of prime ideals
This is a problem from Atiyah-MacDonald Introduction to Commutative Algebra and it goes as follows:
In a ring $A$, let $\Sigma$ be the set of all ideals in which every element is a zero-divisor. Show that the set $\Sigma$ has maximal elements and that every maximal element of $\Sigma$ is a prime ideal.
My proof:
By Zorn's Lemma, a maximal ideal exists and, in particular, it is the union of ideals in a chain. So, for example, let $I = \cup_{\alpha} I_{\alpha}$ where $(I_{\alpha})$ is a chain of ideals.
We assume for contradiction that while $xy \in I$, $x \notin I$ and $y \notin I$. In that case, $x$ and $y$ are non-zero-divisors, so their product cannot be a zero-divisor.
This assumption leads to a contradiction, therefore every maximal element of $\Sigma$ must be a prime ideal.
I saw elsewhere that the proof uses a different argument, by extending the ideal and deriving a contradicon by maximaility. Is my proof valid? Is there anything I should add or elaborate on ?

I don't see how you can conclude that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero-divisors just because they are not in $I$. Not every zero-divisor is in $I$, they might be in some other maximal element of $\Sigma$.

@CaptainLama;  Right, I think I got confused since I considered I to be the unique maximal ideal that is equal to the union of all the ideals. But clearly there are multilpe maximal ideals, for each sequence?

Duplicate of  Showing the set of zero-divisors is a union of prime ideals

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.
